# Non-extractable private key in Keychain on OS X

Tags: macos, security, keychain, private-key, pki

The manual page for `/usr/bin/security` on OS X 10.9 indicates that there is a `-x` option for `security import` to specify that `private keys are non-extractable after being imported`.

How is this implemented?  Are the private keys imported through such means really become completely non-extractable, or is there still a way to get a hold of them through some kind of memory dump?  How do applications still use such keys for their crypto?

Comment: *"Are the private keys imported through such means really become completely non-extractable..."* - considering they make their way to the iCloud and can be recovered by Apple engineers, I don't believe I'd call them non-extractable. You can probably find them in you Time Machine backups, too.

Comment: A similar issue has been discussed here: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2021-May/005455.html with following report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8266439

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how the applications still use such keys, but as per https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/extract-non-extractable-private-key-from-os-x-keychain, it appears that this is simply implemented as a bit attribute for `CSSM_KEYATTR_FLAGS keyAttributes` of `struct SecKeyImportExportParameters` named **`CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE`**.

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/SecurityTool/SecurityTool-55115/keychain_import.c
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecImportExport.h

As per the above, when the import is done, this attribute is specifically omitted when the `-x` option is specified to `security import`.

---

According to SecItem.h, this **`kSecAttrIsExtractable`** has been introduced with OS X 10.6.

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecItem.h

---

Subsequently, when trying to do a wrapped export, several places within the Security framework appear to check to make sure that this `CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE` bit is set prior to doing any kind of export, and return an error in case the attribute is not set.

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecImportExportCrypto.cpp
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471.14/libsecurity_pkcs12/lib/pkcs12Crypto.cpp

Comment: Good thinking on going to opensource.apple.com. I went there too before I saw you answered yourself. By the way, its OK to accept your own answer.

Comment: @jww, I think the question remains of how the apps actually use such keys, so I'll hold off on accepting the answer for now.